# Event receiver for EditTermProperties.aspx

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, event-receivers, term-store, term

Is there an event receiver for page "_layouts/15/EditTermProperties.aspx"? When a user clicks ok to save I need to access before and after properties of that term. Same as we have in custom list event receivers.

[image: _layouts/15/EditTermProperties.aspx]

Answer (score 1):

**As a short answer:** No! there is no event receiver to handle the terms

---

**The Event receiver is available for the below level events:**

- Site/ Web Level Events (`SPWebEventReceiver`).
- List Level Events (`SPListEventReceiver`).
- Item Level Events (`SPItemEventReceiver`).
- Features Level Events (`SPItemEventReceiver`).
- List Workflow Level Events (`SPWorkflowEventReceiver`).
- List Email Level Events (`SPEmailEventReceive`).